# How to 3rd party application access to Yii2 (HumHub)

Tags: php, yii2

I want to give a 3rd party PHP application access to Yii2 user data ([HumHub](https://github.com/humhub/humhub)) and have tried this:

```
    function getUserId() {
      require_once('../protected/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
      $yiiConfig = require('../protected/config/common.php');
      (new humhub\components\Application($yiiConfig));
      $user = Yii::$app->user->identity;

      return $user;
    }
```

This does not work. There are no errors up until `new humhub\components\Application($yiiConfig)` but then the 3rd party app breaks with no error thrown and the function does not return anything.

I did find [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31230098/getting-user-details-with-third-party-app-in-humhub#) which does not work.

Is there are reason this does not work or is there an alternate solution to getting Yii2 user data properly?

Comment: Did you read [**this official**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-yii-integration.html#using-yii-in-others) document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to do it in HumHub V1.0

```
    require_once('../protected/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
    $config = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
        require('../protected/humhub/config/common.php'),
        require('../protected/humhub/config/web.php'),
        (is_readable('../protected/config/dynamic.php')) ? require('../protected/config/dynamic.php') : [],
        require('../protected/config/common.php'),
        require('../protected/config/web.php')
    );
    new yii\web\Application($config); // No 'run()' invocation!
```

Now I can get $user object:

```
   $user = Yii::$app->user->identity;
```

Comment: This is not an answer, just edit your question and add it.

Comment: Why is this not an answer? When I ran the code in the question, it didn't work. When I ran the code in this answer, it worked.

Comment: Oh sorry, I, mistakenly, thought that `HumHub V1.0` is `Yii V1.0`

Answer (score 0):

Indeed an error should be thrown, but, the error settings of your PHP may be overridden or set to not display errors.

You call undefined object `Yii::$app->user->identity`. The reason, from [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-yii-integration.html#using-yii-in-others) because you have not initialized the Yii object. So your code should be as follows:

```
function getUserId() {
      require_once('../protected/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
      $yiiConfig = require('../protected/config/common.php');
      (new humhub\components\Application($yiiConfig)); // try to comment this line too if it does not work
      // Add The Following Line
      new yii\web\Application($yiiConfig); // Do NOT call run() here
      $user = Yii::$app->user->identity;

      return $user;
    }
```